# Line spacing broken (bottom line falls below the frame or even empty) possibly because of the unit of measure of \vspace and images

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, line-spacing, vspace, unit-of-measure

Anytime there's an image on page or otherwise not just pure text (which, of course, is spaced by `\vspace` command) the line spacing gets corrupted.

Take a look at `MWE` below to see. Note how on Page 1 (where PART ONE and Chapter One are) the bottom text line's baseline COINCIDES with the document's frame the way that the font descenders (the portion of letters that extends below the baseline of a font) fall BELOW the frame, while on Page 2 the last line is empty at all!

On Pages 3-5 it's perfectly fine: the bottom text line's baseline is ABOVE the document's frame the way that the font descenders fall WITHIN the frame.

Then Pages 6-7 are again with empty bottom lines and the rest seems fine.

Here's what I'm thinking could be the problem: maybe the fact the `\vspace` commands and/or images I use are set in metric or otherwise not document-related units of measure (like, in, mm, pt, em, ex) is the cause of the page setup's corruption which, as I see it, is measured in quantity of lines, text-wise, of course. I know that the very page is set up either in inches or cm.

In other words, let's assume that the line height is 3mm, then when I tell Tex to add a `\vspace` of 10mm, that 10mm isn't matched by the number of lines (3x3mm=9mm, not 10mm) and that's why, after adding that 10mm, the page is left with some number of lines plus that 2mm extra!

If that's true, is there a way to measure `\vspace` and the dimensions of images in unit of measure that's relative to the document? Like `\lineheight` for instance or simply one line, two lines and etc.? This way `\vspace` and image height would be set in number of lines!

When I tried to modify `\vspace` like this `\vspace{0.5\lineheight}`, it returned an error, though `\vspace{0.5\linewidth}` would strangely work though not giving back the result I want.

If all above is nonsense and not related to the problem, then what is?

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in,inner=15mm,top=15mm,outer=20mm,bottom=22mm,showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalfont\large}{\thepart.}{20pt}{\LARGE\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{10pt}{40pt} 
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalfont\large}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\large\centering}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{30pt}{10pt} 

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    
\begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \vspace*{10mm} 
         {\scshape\huge{TITLE}\par}
        \vspace{0mm}

\end{titlepage}
\clearpage

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\obeylines 

\part{PART ONE}
\vspace{-10mm}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=50mm,height=5mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
  \vspace{0mm}
  \end{center} 
\chapter[CHAPTER ONE]{\begin{center}{CHAPTER ONE} \end{center}} 
\vspace{-10mm}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=100mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
  \vspace{0mm}
  \end{center} 
\lipsum[1-48]
  
 \end{document}
```

Comment: nobody can test your example as we don't have the graphics. Replace them with e.g. `example-image`. And don't use center inside the chapter argument.

Comment: Replaced with `example-image`. Why can't I use center there? As of now it hasn't given any error. And I don't know why `` for code in the question doesn't work.

Comment: remove `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`. Give LaTeX a chance to fill the page.

Comment: `\chapter[CHAPTER ONE]{\begin{center}{CHAPTER ONE} \end{center}}` is completely wrong markup you should no have formatting in a secion heading.

Comment: why do you have explicit `vspace` in the document? the spacing around a section heading should be specified globally, you should not have all this formating in the document. Otherwise it's quite likely that you add spaces that do not fit in the available space, as here

Comment: you can of course use `\vspace{\baselineskip}`  but as I say above you should almost never have such a command in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `heightrounded`: you set `\parskip` with no flexibility, which might be a good thing, but if you don't adjust the text height to contain an integer number of lines, you'll be doomed.

I also commented out the package `nowidow`, because it sets too strict parameters, but that's not mandatory: you'll have to adjust some pages that remain one line short.

There is no need to use `center` inside the title, just define suitably the chapter title formatting: check the changes I made. Since you don't know what's the precise height of the images, I added some flexibility to the spacing after chapter titles.

Finally, I commented out `hyphenat`: there's no point in trying to avoid hyphenation: you only get bad paragraphs.

Finally, `\obeylines` should be removed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=6in,
  paperheight=9in,
  inner=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  outer=20mm,
  bottom=22mm,
  heightrounded,% <---- IMPORTANT
  showframe,
]{geometry} 
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
%\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}{\filcenter\normalfont\large}{\thepart.}{20pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{10pt}{40pt}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\normalfont\large}{\thechapter.}{6pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{10pt plus 10pt}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document} 

\frontmatter
    
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \vspace*{10mm} 
  {\scshape\huge TITLE\par}
\end{titlepage}

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{PART ONE}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=50mm,height=5mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{center} 

\chapter{CHAPTER ONE} 

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=100mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{center} 

\lipsum[1-48]
  
\end{document}
```

If I run this version, I get no `Underfull \vbox` message.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks to you I understood the harmfulness of excessive use of `vspace`! All your comments are much useful and are already incorporated! But Qs, of course (I have a lot but will ask in other posts): what does `heightrounded` do? And if `\obeylines` should be removed, how would I preserve paragraphs if I paste a lot of already written text? It would be torture to do it manually with `\newline`! And `Underfull \vbox`, is that what I find in log file every time I compile? Or some test commands I should include in code? If latter, just point me to the right manual and I'll read it.

Comment: @tryingout To separate paragraphs, simply use a blank line

Comment: I would still have to do it manually because the text is written in word processor without any blank lines, only with paragraph breaks which do not produce any blank lines in Tex after being pasted. Unless I edit text in Word before pasting to Tex and somehow add extra paragraph break after each paragraph?! Otherwise, in Tex I’ll have to manually hit Return after every paragraph to create a blank line :-(

Comment: @tryingout `\obeylines` is really dangerous.

Comment: Now I know. I’ll figure it out. No worries. Thanks again :-)